# How to get specific content (Regex C#)

Tags: c#, html, regex, parsing

I'm using regular regular expressions in C# and have following string:

```
<tr>
<td class="uk-text-bold">Hello</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="uk-text-bold">World</td>
</tr>
```

Using this pattern:
`<td class=\"uk-text-bold\">(.+?)</td>`

I'm trying to get just "Hello" and "World", so everything between brackets, but it keeps returning the full line and I'm stuck.

Can I get some advice?

Regular expression [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3ctd+class%3d%5c%22uk-text-bold%5c%22%3e(.%2b%3f)%3c%2ftd%3e&i=%3ctr%3e%0d%0a%3ctd+class%3d%22uk-text-bold%22%3eHello%3c%2ftd%3e%0d%0a%3c%2ftr%3e%0d%0a%3ctr%3e%0d%0a%3ctd+class%3d%22uk-text-bold%22%3eWorld%3c%2ftd%3e%0d%0a%3c%2ftr%3e&o=insm).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use regex, use HtmlAgilityPack or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression is ok. So, if you really need to use Regex, I reccomend you to use named groups instead of numbered ones and then iterate through matches and process that named group. For example:

```
var pattern = @"<td class=\""uk-text-bold\"">(?<mostwanted>.+?)</td>";
var input = @"<tr>
<td class=""uk-text-bold"">Hello</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class=""uk-text-bold"">World</td>
</tr>";

var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);

var matches = regex.Matches(input);

foreach (var mostwanted in matches
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(t1 => t1.Groups["mostwanted"].Value))
{
  Console
   .WriteLine(mostwanted);
}
```

But, as the others says, better way is to use some html parser (HtmlAgilityPack is very good). Because, if your html code will contains spaces between tags or there will be some unwanted returns, your regex will be broken.

Comment: The numbered group he was using works just as well; he just needed to know how to access it.  Also, there's no call for the `Multiline` option.  All it does is change the meaning of the anchors (`^` and `$`) from whole-string boundaries to line boundaries, and there are no anchors in the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a `Match m`, use `m.Groups[1].Value` instead of `m.Value`. Each pair of parenthesis define a new group.

But to tell you how you should *really* do it, use an HTML parsing library for parsing HTML, not regex.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is good. To get your value you must iterate through groups

[image]

To parse Html you should use a dedicated library without using regex. You can take a look here for using HTML agility pack : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9b86d4/getting-started-with-html-agility-pack/